# Tensorflow c_api decision forest savedModel loaded but status is not TF_OK

Tags: c, tensorflow, machine-learning, c-api

I am using tensorflow decision forests. I trained my model using Python and saved the model with **SavedModel** format. Then for inference I am trying to load the model in C using tensorflow C_API. I found that for this task I need to load the decision forest `inference.so` file from Python package.

You can use this command in Debian 10 to install Python package:

`pip3 install tensorflow-decision-forests`

After that in my program I load the `inference.so` file using `TF_LoadLibrary`. Then I load the model using `TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel`.

***Here is the code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
  TF_Graph *Graph = TF_NewGraph();
  TF_Status *Status = TF_NewStatus();
  TF_SessionOptions *SessionOpts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
  TF_Buffer *RunOpts = NULL;
  TF_Library *library;

  library = TF_LoadLibrary("/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_decision_forests/tensorflow/ops/inference/inference.so",
                              Status);

  const char *saved_model_dir = "randomforests-model/";
  const char *tags = "serve";
  int ntags = 1;

  TF_Session *Session = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(
      SessionOpts, RunOpts, saved_model_dir, &tags, ntags, Graph, NULL, Status);

  printf("status: %s\n", TF_Message(Status));

  if(TF_GetCode(Status) == TF_OK) {
    printf("loaded\n");
  }else{
    printf("not loaded\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

***Output***

```
$ gcc -g main.c -ltensorflow -o main.out
user@debian:/home/code/tftest$ ./main.out 
Hello from TensorFlow C library version 2.7.0-dev20211101
2022-01-22 19:39:28.539621: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:43] Reading SavedModel from: randomforests-mtproto-model-001028/
2022-01-22 19:39:28.547223: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:107] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2022-01-22 19:39:28.547792: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:148] Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) from: randomforests-mtproto-model-001028/
2022-01-22 19:39:28.548298: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-01-22 19:39:28.598841: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:210] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2022-01-22 19:39:28.743885: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:194] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: randomforests-mtproto-model-001028/
[INFO kernel.cc:1153] Loading model from path
[INFO decision_forest.cc:617] Model loaded with 300 root(s), 618972 node(s), and 28 input feature(s).
[INFO abstract_model.cc:1063] Engine "RandomForestOptPred" built
[INFO kernel.cc:1001] Use fast generic engine
2022-01-22 19:39:30.922861: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:283] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 2383248 microseconds.

status: No shape inference function exists for op 'SimpleMLLoadModelFromPathWithHandle', did you forget to define it?
not loaded
```

The problem is that the function output is telling that the model is loading with `Status: success: OK` but the `Status` variable is no equal to `TF_OK` and the related message is `No shape inference function exists for op 'SimpleMLLoadModelFromPathWithHandle', did you forget to define it?`

So how can I load the model in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time and didn't get an answer, I asked the question in the TensorFlow's forum and get the [answer](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/decision-forests-issue-with-c-api/7434).
It seems that the current version of `TensorFlow` has a problem with loading decision forests with C_API. So we can use the `Yggdrasil` library as discussed in the answer.